# Adding Objects to JS Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to create an `array` of `objects` that contain two pieces of information relating to an order:

1. Product Stock Code
2. Product Quantity

Currently I am doing it like this:

```
$(".orderBtn").click(function(event){

        //Show the order Box
        $(".order-alert").show();
        event.preventDefault();

        //Create the Array
        var productArray = [];
        //Get reference to the product clicked
        var stockCode = $(this).closest('li').find('.stock_code').html();
        //Get reference to the quantity selected
        var quantity = $(this).closest('li').find('.order_amount').val();

        var key = "stockCode";
        var obj = {
            'stockCode' : stockCode,
            'quantity'  : quantity
        };

        productArray.push(obj);

        $.cookie('order_cookie', JSON.stringify(productArray), { expires: 1, path: '/' });

        console.log(productArray);

        if(quantity == 0){
            console.log("Quantity must be greater than 0")
        }
```

I would expect that each time the order button is clicked that the new object would be added to the `array` of existing objects but instead It just outputs the `array` with 1 object, the object I've just added.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: replace var productArray = []; outside click function

Comment: Each time the function runs, you create a new array. Move its declaration out of the event handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your array declaration outside of the function into the global scope.
What happens in your case is that each time you call the function a new array is created(function scope) and therefore only one result is produced.

Read [this](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-variable-scope-and-hoisting-explained/) about scopes\hoistings.

```
var productArray = [];
$(".orderBtn").click(function(event){

        //Show the order Box
        $(".order-alert").show();
        event.preventDefault();

        //Create the Array

        //Get reference to the product clicked
        var stockCode = $(this).closest('li').find('.stock_code').html();
        //Get reference to the quantity selected
        var quantity = $(this).closest('li').find('.order_amount').val();

        var key = "stockCode";
        var obj = {
            'stockCode' : stockCode,
            'quantity'  : quantity
        };

        productArray.push(obj);

        $.cookie('order_cookie', JSON.stringify(productArray), { expires: 1, path: '/' });

        console.log(productArray);

        if(quantity == 0){
            console.log("Quantity must be greater than 0")
        }
```

Comment: That was it, don't know how I missed that!! Thank you, will accept answer in 10 minutes when I am allowed to

Answer (score 2):

declare as global variable

```
 var productArray = [];
    $(".orderBtn").click(function(event){
    // do here 
    //productArray.push("anyObject"); 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are recreating / overwriting the productArray every time the button is clicked.  Try moving the `var productArray = []` to outside of the click handler

Answer (score 0):

Not so, because your

```
var productArray = [];
```

is within the function that sets the cookie, so it's getting defined afresh then having one element added each time the function is called.

You'd need to define   productArray outside of the function (as a global variable?) so that it retains its previous value, and new objects are added to it

Answer (score 0):

With `var productArray = [];` you're declaring a new array on every click. Move that line outside the click handler and the code should start working.